# preg_match to check if string has specific structure

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I check with php with `preg_match()` if string has specific structure. For example string is:

```
options:blue;white;yellow;
```

I want to check if string starts with string followed by `:` followed by n-numbers of strings separated by `;`

And something which is important - string may be in Cyrillic, not only latin letters

Comment: A specific number of strings separated by `;`? Is the encoding UTF-8?

Comment: yes, utf-8 is the encoding

Comment: Can the strings contain numbers or symbols?

Comment: the string may contain both, thanks

Comment: Ok, see my answer, that should do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming only the restrictions listed in your question are needed, this will validate the string:

```
$number = 3;
$regex = sprintf('/^[^:]+:(?:[^;]+;){%d}$/', $number);

if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    echo "It matches!";
} else {
    echo "It doesn't match!";
}
```

Here's an example of it in action, using `php -a`:

```
php > $number = 3;
php > $regex = sprintf('/^[^:]+:(?:[^;]+;){%d}$/', $number);

php > if (preg_match($regex, 'options:blue;white;yellow;')) {
php {     echo "It matches!";
php { } else {
php {     echo "It doesn't match!";
php { }
It matches!

php > if (preg_match($regex, 'options:blue;white;yellow;green;')) {
php {     echo "It matches!";
php { } else {
php {     echo "It doesn't match!";
php { }
It doesn't match!
```

You can visualize this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/tA2aP6/2). Let's break it down:

```
/.../          Start and end of the pattern.
^              Start of the string.
[^:]+          At least one character that is not a ':'.
:              A literal ':'.
(?:[^;]+;){N}  Exactly N occurrences of:
                   [^;]+  At least one character that is not a ';'.
                   ;      A literal ';'.
$              End of the string.
```

Comment: #Will, after I tested it I can confirm it partitially works. I suppose $number = 3 defines the number of options, but as I said it will have n-number of options which makes the task more complicated, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand... `$number` is your `n`. If you know beforehand how many to expect, set `$number` to that number. Or, do you mean you don't know what `n` will be?

Comment: yes Will, but I sorted out by changing this to: $number = count(explode(';',rtrim($_POST['addoptions'],";"))); It is working as expected, thanks !

Comment: Perfect, no problem, glad to help! :)